# Ссылка на класс или делегат

Tags: c#

Привет всем.

По мере углубления в изучении языка c# все больше задаюсь вопросом, для чего нужно это или то. Так как я самоучка и пишу программу методом тыка, в моих кодах хакер ногу сломит. Но все же пишу программки. Конечно, может, я их пишу неправильно, но конечный результат -  все работает.

Проблема в том, что мне некого спрашивать, чтобы получить точный адекватный ответ. У меня нет знакомых программистов.

Вот, например, вопрос про делегаты. Если мне нужно вызвать события из другого класса, я могу написать ссылку на этот класс и через переменную вызвать события. Зачем тогда нужен делегат? Ведь в принципе он несет  то же самое, что и просто ссылка на класс, возможно, я еще не пишу какие-то сложные программы, чтоб оценивать преимущество делегатов. Я уже молчу про интерфейсы. Сколько не читал про них, и все как один пишут - они нужны и сними удобно. В моем понятии  это лишняя писанина кода. Опять же повторюсь, может, я еще не пишу сложные программы, чтоб это оценить.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > я самоучка и пишу программу методом тыка

а почему бы вам не прочитать какую-нибудь хорошую книгу по языку? Там эти вопросы подробно освещаются. Иначе ваше самообучение будет долгим и трудным, и, возможно даже, ни к чему хорошему не приведет, либо вам придется потратить в несколько раз больше времени и сил на то, чтобы понять очевидные вещи

Comment: Вот и вы вроде бы ответили. Что это очевидно, но не пояснили. Я понимаю, что это не зря придумано и си Шарп разрабатывали люди в тыча раз умнее меня. А на счет литературы кончена нужна, и я постоянно читаю что-то новое. Обычно ищу инфу для конкретного интересующего меня вопроса. Читал, например, всеми хваленного Герберт Шилдт. Но и там не все так чисто и доходчиво.

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев я бы с удовольствием вам ответил, но ответ на этот вопрос требует довольно длительного объяснения - к сожалению объяснять вам придется многое в силу того, что знания ваши весьма поверхностны судя по всему. Написать здесь подробное объяснение я к сожалению сейчас не могу, постараюсь сделать это чуть позже, когда будет время

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев: Да простит меня @DreamChild, но я бы не рекомендовал и не хвалил Шилдта. Поищите по форуму, вопрос хорошей литературы обсуждался [неоднократно](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+книги+site%3Ahashcode.ru).

Comment: @VladD я его также не хвалю, просто не поддерживаю обвинения в его адрес по любому поводу. Но в любом случае и помимо Шилдта есть куча замечательных авторов. Для начинающего подойдет Троелсен, вероятно, Албахари плюс какая-нибудь литература по основам ООП

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Небольшой пример про делегаты**

Иногда может сложиться такая ситуация, что вы точно не знаете имя метода, который надо передать в стороннюю функцию, но она должна быть унифицирована. К тому же делегаты можно складывать.

Типичный пример с сортировками.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public delegate void TypeSort(ref int[] arr);

    static public class SortMethod{
        static public void Inc(ref int[] arr)
        {
            int j, k;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                    {
                        k = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                        arr[j + 1] = k;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                while (j < arr.Length - 1);
            }
        }

        static public void Dec(ref int[] arr)
        {
            int j, k;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                j = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1])
                    {
                        k = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                        arr[j + 1] = k;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                while (j < arr.Length - 1);
            }
        }

        static public void Write(ref int[] arr)
        {
            Console.Write("Массив: ");
            foreach (int i in arr)
                Console.Write("{0}\t", i);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] myArr = new int[6] { 2, -4, 10, 5, -6, 9 };

            TypeSort typesort = new TypeSort(SortMethod.Write);
            typesort += SortMethod.Inc;
            typesort += SortMethod.Write;
            typesort += SortMethod.Dec;
            typesort += SortMethod.Write;

            typesort(ref myArr);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае методы выполняются в Main, но практика использования делегатов в том, что они передаются в другие функции, которые не должны жестко кодировать используемый метод.

**Небольшой пример про интерфейсы**

Другой дело с интерфейсами, они нужны для четкого описания того, что есть в классе. К примеру, вы делаете приложение, которое выполняет подключение к БД. Вам надо сделать подключение в трем типам СУБД по выбору: MySQL, SQL SERVER и Oracle. Вы могли бы делать для каждого свой класс и таскать их, но проще таскать интерфейс, не зная реализации класса.

```
public interface IDBConnect
{
    public bool Query(String query);
}

public class MSSQL : IDBConnect
{
    public bool Query(string query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Запрос к MSSQL");
        return true;
    }
}

public class MySQL : IDBConnect
{
    public bool Query(string query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Запрос к MySQL");
        return true;
    }
}

public class Oracle : IDBConnect
{
    public bool Query(string query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Запрос к Oracle");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Теперь код, который использует подключения, может не думать о внутренней реализации этих подключений и выполнять их через интерфейс.

```
public class useConnect
{
    IDBConnect connect;

    useConnect(IDBConnect con)
    {
        connect = con;
    }

    public void useQuery()
    {
        connect.Query("Запрос");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите базу:");
        String DBase = Console.ReadLine();

        UseConnect connect;
        switch(DBase){
            case "MSSQL":
                connect = new UseConnect(new MSSQL());
                break;
            case "MySQL":
                connect = new UseConnect(new MySQL());
                break;
            default:
                connect = new UseConnect(new Oracle());
                break;
        }

        /* теперь нашему connect все равно, что там за база на самом деле */
        connect.useQuery();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

К тому же стоит заметить, что очень легко добавить новую базу (или абсолютно полностью переписать старую), унаследовав интерфейс и не меняя весь остальной код. Еще тут выполняется полиморфизм, вы всегда знаете, какие методы может иметь тот или иной класс, глядя на его интерфейс. Это также позволяет Вам писать свои классы на этом интерфейсе. Часто используемый пример - это встроенные IQueryable и IEnumerable, унаследовавшись от которых, ваши собственные классы могут реализовать правильное поведение "Как массив" для обращений по индексу myClass[1] и "Как перечисление" для foreach(var in myClass) { ... }.

**Ну и поскольку тут поднималась тема про книги, то вот хороший список:**

[Классические книги по C#/.NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/cnet.html)

**UPD**

В дополнение, часто используются делегаты для подписывания (и отписывания с помощью операции -=) на события.

```
public delegate void EventComplete();
class First{
    public EventComplete Complete;

    public void Do(){
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Complete();
    }
}

class Second
{
    public void Ok()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Класс First выполнил действие");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        First obj = new First();
        obj.Complete += new EventComplete( new Second().Ok );
        obj.Complete += new EventComplete( new Second().Ok );
        obj.Do();
    }
}
```

Это только то, что вспомнил сразу, там еще есть много ситуаций, где удобны классы и интерфейсы для применения.

Comment: Также стоит отметить, что большинство библиотек как раз использует делегаты и по поводу приведенных интерфейсов, есть такая замечательная вещь, как внедрение зависимостей (Ninject). После этого интерфейсы кажутся очень удобными.

Comment: Спасибо. Начинаю потихоньку вникать и в интерфейс, и в делегат. Осталось примерить на практике, и начну полностью осознавать. Обычно я придумываю простенькие задачки, в которых нужно использовать новый материал. Как только я это реализую и все пройдет, тогда я усваиваю материал. Огромное спасибо всем, кто поддержал эту тему. У кого есть еще примеры, с интерфейсом и делегатом, прошу написать. Только так не сильно заумные.

Comment: На счет интерфейса. Вроде все понятно, только ничего не понятно :)
Написал, как вы написали, все работает отлично.
Даже перекрутил к своему проекту. Только я так и не понял, для чего нужен класс useConnect. Получается просто как прокладка между классам MSSQL  и class Program. Тогда опять непонятно получается, опять лишняя писанина кода.
Ладно закрыли тему. Спасибо всем.

Comment: @Alex Krass . На счет new, ну конечно было просто сказано. А на счет всего остального. Ну в случае если пользователь сам вводит имя базы то да. А в остальном , не понятно. Поймите я не коем случае не спорю с вами. Сто процентов вы правы. Просто я хочу досконально понять их преимущество, ваш пример это единственный показатель тому что да так удобней. А все остальные примеров что есть в интернете, так там действительно пример пустой писанины кода

Answer (score 3):

Делегат и правда семантически не сильно отличается от ссылки на сам класс плюс указания, какой метод нужно вызывать. В Java делегатов нет, и там приходится делать именно так.

Однако, как показывает практика, такой подход приводит к довольно громоздкому коду.

Сравните:

C#/WPF

```
void SetupUpdate(DispatcherTimer timer)
{
    timer.Tick += (o, args) =>
        {
            var currentSeconds = DateTime.Now.Second;
            textBlock.Text = string.Format("{0} sec", currentSeconds);
        };
}
```

Аналог на Java/Swing

```
void SetupUpdate(javax.swing.Timer timer) {
    final JTextField innerTextField = textField; // для замыкания
    timer.AddActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Calender now = Calendar.getInstance();
                int seconds = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                innerTextField.setText(String.format("%d sec", seconds));
            }
    );
}
```

---

Справедливости ради, должен отметить, что в свежей версии Java есть такие же делегаты/лямбда-функции, так что синтаксис стал похожим.

Comment: @DreamChild спасибо. Меня не надо учить как создавать делегат. Хоть и по этому поводу есть вопросы. Вопрос состоит в том, как правильней делать ссылку на класс и вызывать метод или делать ссылку на делегат. На что это влияет? Может, от множество ссылок на классы это влияет на производительность программы или что-то другое. Насчет обильности кода, так вызывать метод с помощью ссылки на класс, получается на одну строчку меньше писать придется. Опять же повторюсь, я не пишу огромные программы, чтобы оценивать преимущество.

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев: Я не пытался объяснить вам, как создавать делегат, я пытался показать синтаксическое преимущество. И мне кажется, там разница не в одной строке, а в обилии boilerplate: без делегатов получается много кода, который не говорит то, что вы думаете, а просто нужен для обвязки.

По поводу семантических преимуществ, всё сложнее. На мой вкус, обычно я сообщаю источнику событий лишь _действие_, которое он должен инициировать, поэтому делегат семантически ближе к тому, как я думаю. Если же вам кажется, что кроме самого действия важен также и объект, который его выполняет, ...

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев: ... то правильнее будет передавать объект.

То есть, форма записи диктуется семантикой, а не каким-то догматическим правилом, действующем раз и навсегда.

Итак, в каждом случае выбирать стоит именно вам как архитектору программы. У меня в подавляющем большинстве сам объект не важен, а важно лишь действие. YMMV.

Comment: Облазил весь Гугл. Кроме как ссылки на мой вопрос, ничего интересного не нашел. Пусть простят меня программисты, но, как не крути, интерфейсы это лишняя писанина кода. Даже исходя из примера по подключения к базе данных. Вам приходится создавать класс подключения к базе, к примеру, Mysql создать для него интерфейс. Потом написать класс "перегрузчика" useConnect. С ссылкой на интерфейс. Потом еще ссылок в main классе.

Comment: даже если мне надо написать класс подключения к другой базе то мне все равно нужно писать класса и трогать main класс . Все это можно делать двумя строчками . Ссылкой на класс и через переменную передавать методы. Две строчки заменяют целую писанину. Так где преимущество?

Comment: Единственное, что, может, это как-то влияет на производительность программы из-за частого использования new. Хоть в вашем случае их такое число. В общем, перемудрили.

Comment: > как не крути интерфейсы это лишняя писанина кода

не пишите бреда. Если вы чего-то не понимаете, это не не означает, что это бесполезно. Это лишь означает, что вам надо учить основы. 

>Единственное что может это как-то влияет на производительность программы , из-за частого использования new

это уж, пардон, вообще за гранью разумного

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев, если хотите, можете задать отдельно вопрос по тому, где применяются интерфейсы, тут уже не так много места. А вообще, интерфейсы нужны для понимания, что может класс, не зная ничего о нем конкретного. Вот у меня там один класс useConnect, а представьте, что их теперь стало таких пятьдесят с множеством методов. И теперь в программе есть выбор пользователя что использовать, MSSQL или MySQL, что вы будете делать? У меня там стоит тип IDBConnect, а вы будете плодить сто под каждый тип данных? А если я еще пару условий добавлю? И это только одно из преимуществ интерфейсов.