# Интерфейс и  его примеры

Tags: c#

Привет всем!

В продолжение темы [Ссылка на класс или делегат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394376#394649), где уважаемый @Alex Krass пытался мне объяснить, какая польза от применения интерфейса.

Для меня все так же остается загадкой. Я все так же считаю, что это лишняя писанина кода.
За это время я почитал немало статей про интерфейс и просмотрел видеокурс.
Но так и не разобрался. Честно сказать, я не знаю, почему я зациклился на нем, ведь не знал бы о его существовании, давно бы закончил писать свой проект.

Вот, к примеру, Алекс объясняет, что в его примере он с легкостью может добавить еще 100 классов useConnect, но, на мой взгляд, ему также нужно 100 раз вызывать `connect = new UseConnect(ссылка на класс());`, причем в его конкретном случае ему придется плодить switch, чтобы вызвать все классы. Причем я так и не понял, как в таком случае можно добраться до метода из какого-либо класса, в том примере их можно вызвать только все кучей. Причем если в главном классе мне нужно будет еще раз использовать какой-нибудь метод, то мне опять придется переписывать `connect = new UseConnect(ссылка на класс());`. В моем же случае, где я просто пишу ссылку на класс и через переменную вызываю метод, так я эту переменную могу использовать где захочу и когда захочу, причем могу вызвать любой из методов. Да и вообще мне 
не придется писать класс UseConnect, я могу вызывать методы сразу, в данном примере из класса MySQL, к примеру.

Вот реальный пример, который мне нужно реализовать в своем примере. Опять же повторюсь, с помощью ссылки на классы я уже эту задачу решал. Просто хочу посмотреть, как решают такую задачу профи, с помощью интерфейсов.

Вот пример. У меня есть форма, в которой пользователь может сохранять записи в базе данных. В моем случае MySQL. Он может внести запись, после вызвать ее и сделать изменения. 
У меня есть пять классов. Главный, который вызывает форму, класс инсерт, класс упдата, класс селест и класс подключения к базе. Класс инсерт упдата и селект наследуют класс подключения к базе. Ну это я так решил сделать, чтобы не использовать интерфейс. Вот и сама задача: как мне эти четыре класса с помощью интефейса(ов) подключить к главному классу с формой.

Ну, я это так для моего примера взял.
Лучше, конечно, приведите, явный пример, где интерфейс облегчает жизнь программисту.
Прошу не заводить тему моей грамотности и знания русского языка. Эту тему мы уже обсуждали и я не раз говорил о причине моей безграмотности русского языка. И так же не посылайте меня за книжкой, ну если только посоветуете хорошую.

Comment: Интерфейс, в первую очередь интересен для межклассового взаимодействия. 

Например, если далеко не ходить, есть стандартный интерфейс (ISortable)

И есть стандартный класс который сортирует объекты ISortable (не помню уже какой).

Без интерфейсов, Вы бы не могли использовать этот класс для сортировки своих коллекций, и, пришлось бы реализовывать свой метод сортировки.

А так, Вы реализуете в своём классе только необходимые методы, и пользуетесь всем спектром вспомогательных классов для операций над ними.

И это только вершина айсберга.

Comment: @Чад Я все прекрасно понимаю, C# придумали люди в 1000 раз умней меня. И, естественно, интерфейс нужен. Но как им работать, до меня так и не доходит, в плане того, что я не пойму, где его превосходство. Ведь для меня это еще больше писанина кода, и если мне нужно будет добавить класс, то мне все так же нужно курочить, к примеру, главный класс. В конечном итоге мы так же создаем ссылку на класс и вызываем методы. Иак где смысл?

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев вы явно топчетесь на одном месте. Даже не знаю, какими еще словами вам это объяснить. Лучше забудьте пока про интерфейсы, вероятно, потом в процессе профессионального развития сможете понять их преимущество опытным путем.

Comment: @DreamChild Спасибо за совет. Я тоже об этом подумывал. Но все же хотелось бы разобраться на начальной стадии своего развития, ведь впереди еще делегаты. :)

Comment: незнаю чо там у вас, шарпистов, а у меня в яве всё просто - объявил коллекцию List<Animal> и храни в ней объекты не класса а интерфейса. 

 1. Cat implements Animal
 2. Dog implements Animal
 3. Rabbit implements Animal


 А иначе этих зверушек в коллекцию не запихнуть!!

Comment: @argamidon Ага! А на php так вообще все просто: есть include, и толкай его, куда хочешь. :)

Comment: >А иначе этих зверушек в коллекцию не запихнуть!!

почему же никак? Как минимум еще подойдет класс-предок. Более того, это не самый удачный пример, поскольку в случае с животными скорее абстрактный класс подходит, нежели интерфейс - даже название базовой сущности не соответствует правилам именования интерфейсов ни в Java ни в C# 

> Но все-же хотелось бы разобраться на начальной стадии своего развития, ведь впереди еще делегаты :).

@Геннадий Писарев судя по вашей стадии впереди у вас не только делегаты, а еще много куда более важных тем для изучения

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев, инетерфейс создан не для замены, превосходства, а в дополнение. Без него невозможно реализовать такое понятие, как множественное наследование, когда Вам надо, чтобы один объект мог иметь одновременно свойства как одного, так и другого класса. Ну прям как корпускулярно-волновая теория света. :-D Посмотрите ответ @Alex Krass, считаю его очень подробным.

Comment: Вот видео-урок, который (в силу популярности изложения) лично мне помог понять вопрос о том, для чего нужны "интерфейсы" в C#: - [Уроки C#. Интерфейсы.](https://youtu.be/FQf14kj8HwU) - [Уроки C#. Пример создания приложения](https://youtu.be/N6RNy3rPZpg)

Answer (score 15):

Сейчас Вам, скорее всего, это не надо, Вы столкнетесь с этим когда-нибудь позже, когда будете готовы. Не заморачивайтесь и идите дальше, очень часто программисты вынуждены пропускать темы и возвращаться к ним. Главное, что Вы знаете, что есть такая вещь, как интерфейс, и она позволяет скрывать реальные реализации классов.

С помощью интерфейсов Вы:

- не завязываете логику своего приложения с конкретными классами и можете легко вносить изменения в одни классы, не трогая другие, добавлять функциональность или заменить один класс абсолютно другим, не трогая все приложение. То есть реализуется абстракция от реализации;
- можете проектировать логику приложений на интерфейсах, оставив реализацию на потом и применяя заглушки;
- применять так называемое множественное наследование;
- если будете начальником, сможете легко донести свои мысли до подчиненных (реализуй мне функциональность вот этого интерфейса).

Я дам несколько примеров, в которых применяется интерфейс, но сразу оговорюсь, они не являются лучшими представителями. Ведь я тоже учусь. )

**Проектирование недозоопарка**

Давайте запроектируем небольшую программу зоопарка, при этом зоопарк у нас бужет пошаговым.

***1. В первую очередь его стоит населить животными, которые умеют ходить по нему, приступим.***

Для описания жизненного цикла зоопарка я использую класс ZooLivecycle:

```
    class ZooLivecycle
{
    public void allPetWalk()
    {

    }
}
```

Итак, у нас есть животные, которые умеют ходить, давайте определим их возможности через интерфейсы и реализуем.

```
interface IWalk 
{ 
    void walk();
}
class Cat : IWalk
{
    public void walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cat walk");
    }
}
class Dog : IWalk
{
    public void walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog walk");
    }
}
class Fish : IWalk
{
    public void walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fish cant walk");
    }
}
class Bird : IWalk
{
    public void walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("bird can fly");
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы все животные ходили, проще их передать в класс зоопарка всем массивом и пройтись по ним циклом.

```
class ZooLivecycle
{
    public void allPetWalk(IWalk[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            arr[i].walk();
    }
}
```

Итак, теперь можно вызывать нашу реализацию.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZooLivecycle zoo = new ZooLivecycle();

        IWalk[] walks = new IWalk[]{new Cat(), new Dog(), new Fish(), new Bird()};

        Console.WriteLine("\n*Pet Walk*");
        zoo.allPetWalk(walks);

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

А теперь попробуйте реализовать это без интерфейсов, главным образом функцию allPetWalk, хотя есть способ - это общий класс родитель. Можно также попробовать передавать ссылку как `public void allPetWalk(Object[] arr)` и потом приводить типы, но это является очень плохой практикой, так как вы теряете контроль над типами и вынуждены добавлять проверки, что не является лучшим решением.

***2. Идем дальше, мы решили добавить систему наблюдения, а именно видеокамеры, которая сможет передавать информацию.***

```
interface IObservation
{
    void analyze();
}
class Videocamera : IObservation
{
    public void analyze()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In zoo all ok");
    }
}
```

Реализуем получение информации в классе зоопарка:

```
class ZooLivecycle
{
    public void allPetWalk(IWalk[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            arr[i].walk();
    }
    public void zooAnalyze(IObservation[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            arr[i].analyze();
    }
}
```

Ну и вызов.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZooLivecycle zoo = new ZooLivecycle();

        IWalk[] walks = new IWalk[]{new Cat(), new Dog(), new Fish(), new Bird()};
        IObservation[] analyze = new IObservation[] { new Videocamera() };

        Console.WriteLine("\n*Pet Walk*");
        zoo.allPetWalk(walks);
        Console.WriteLine("\n*Analyze zoo*");
        zoo.zooAnalyze(analyze);

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

***3. А теперь давайте подложим свинью, если кто-то все еще использовал класс родитель, вместо интерфейсов.***

Реализуем помошника, который может как ходить по зоопарку, так и передавать информацию. В языке C# нет перекрестного наследования, но зато можно наследовать несколько интерфейсов вместо этого.

```
class HelperPet : IWalk, IObservation
{
    public void walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("helppet walk");
    }

    public void analyze()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("helppet analyze");
    }
}
```

Это все, что пришлось добавить. Можно дальше пользоваться нашим зоопарком, ничего не переписывая.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZooLivecycle zoo = new ZooLivecycle();

        IWalk[] walks = new IWalk[]{new Cat(), new Dog(), new Fish(), new Bird(), new HelperPet()};
        IObservation[] analyze = new IObservation[] { new Videocamera(), new HelperPet() };

        Console.WriteLine("\n*Pet Walk*");
        zoo.allPetWalk(walks);
        Console.WriteLine("\n*Analyze zoo*");
        zoo.zooAnalyze(analyze);

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

**Теперь давайте рассмотрим реальные примеры, которые очень часто используются.**

Очень часто интерфейсы используются как описательные модели, наследование от которых дает возможность работать с тем, для чего они созданы. Тем самым вы не привязываетесь к конкретным классам. В самом языке очень C# даже есть интерфейсы, которые реализуют то или иное поведение. Вы очень часто будете с этим сталкиваться, если перейдете на WPF или ASP.NET MVC приложения.

***Использование foreach с собственными классами***

Давайте улучшим наш зоопарк и добавим класс для хранения животных. Несмотря на то, что он довольно объемный, я просто [взял с MSDN пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) и просто подставил свои значения.

```
    public interface IWalk 
{ 
    void walk();
}

    public class Animals : IEnumerable<IWalk>
{
    private IWalk[] _pets;
    public Animals(IWalk[] pArray)
    {
        _pets = new IWalk[pArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _pets[i] = pArray[i];
        }
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }

    public PetsEnum GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PetsEnum(_pets);
    }

    IEnumerator<IWalk> IEnumerable<IWalk>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<IWalk>)GetEnumerator();
    }
}
public class PetsEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public IWalk[] _pets;

    int position = -1;

    public PetsEnum(IWalk[] list)
    {
        _pets = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _pets.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public IWalk Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _pets[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}

Теперь я могу делать так:
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ZooLivecycle zoo = new ZooLivecycle();

        Animals animals = new Animals(new IWalk[]{new Cat(), new Dog(), new Fish(), new Bird(), new HelperPet()});

        Console.WriteLine("\n*Pet Walk*");
        zoo.allPetWalk(animals);

        Console.Read();
    }

}

class ZooLivecycle
{
    public void allPetWalk(Animals animals)
    {
        foreach(IWalk animal in animals) 
            animal.walk();
    }
}
```

Не реализовав интерфейс, вы не сможете использовать с вашим классом foreach, хотя на самом деле это делается очень быстро. При этом метод foreach работает с любыми объектами, и не будь интерфейсов, достигнуть такого эффекта было бы сложнее. Теперь в класс Animals можно добавить такие методы, как Add, Remove, etc.

***Ну и в конце концов вы можете ставить заглушки и передавать тестовые данные.***

Если реализация классов достаточно сложна, например, один из них получает данные из базы, а другой обрабатывает эти данные, то вы можете написать ненастоящий класс. То есть вместо реальных данных Вы передаете класс, которые не использует подключение к БД, и потом его можно будет переписать. Причем можно работать нормально как с одним, так и с другим классом попеременно.